# speed up parse function dateutil

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

Using dateutil I created function which check if data from csv is date and if not remove it from dataframe, but I have problem with speed, similar checking for string or int takes 1-2 seconds for hundreds of thousands rows, but this takes more than 1 minute for date checking. I need some tips, how to speed up this, maybe there is some function from pandas library

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|', dtype=str)
for i, ColumnValueDate in enumerate(df[column]):
     try:
        df.loc[i, column[0]] = parse(str(ColumnValueDate)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    except ParserError as ex:
        dataframeIndexToDelete.append(i)
        print(ex)
df = df.drop(dataframeIndexToDelete)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) on the column, with `errors='coerce'` and then remove all values which are [`NaT`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.NaT.html#pandas.NaT) (not a time):

```
df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column], errors='coerce')
df = df[~df[column].isna()]
```

If you don't want to modify the dataframe, use a temporary Series instead:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df[column], errors='coerce')
df = df[~dates.isna()]
```

**Update**

Based on comments, `df[column]` could have `NaN` or empty (`''`) values which should not be excluded. This requires making a second mask to ensure they are in the output even though the date conversion will fail:

```
m1 = (df['Date'].isna()) | (df['Date'] == '')
m2 = ~pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').isna()

df = df[m1 | m2]
```

Comment: Thank for quick response, It will check that, but it will work with empty strings? I want to keep NaN values, just remove fields with wrong format

Comment: @Southsun1 could you have `NaN` values in the date column?

Comment: yes, coz it is available field but not required, dataframe is inserted into database in next step

Comment: @Southsun1 please see my edit. That should ensure that rows where the data value was `NaN` or `''` will be retained in the output.